# How to Retrieve Selected Channel ID After Slack OAuth Redirection?

Tags: integration, slack, slack-api

In my Slack workspace and app, I've created a workflow where users need to choose a channel for posting updates from my application. To facilitate this, I've constructed a Slack authentication URL that opens a Slack interface, allowing users to select a channel from a list.

[image]

```
slackURL = `https://akash.slack.com/oauth?client_id=${CLIENTID}&scope=incoming-webhook&user_scope=&redirect_uri=https://localhost:3000/connect/slack&state=y1MkhEKd80A3oauzgsFWBE38f4Sme4uQp7JD7w93&granular_bot_scope=1&single_channel=0&install_redirect=update-to-granular-scopes&tracked=1&team=`;
```

Once a channel is selected, Slack redirects back to the specified redirect URL with a code and state. However, I'm uncertain about how to retrieve the selected channel ID or any related information after this redirection. Is there a step I might be missing or something I should adjust in this process? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.